# Can I use Suitescript SuiteQl to get the pnrefnum on a Cash Sale?

Tags: netsuite, suitescript2.0, suiteql

I am trying to use SuiteQL to get the pnrefenum on a Cash Sale. It is not coming back when I query the Transaction, and while I suspect that it is possible to retrieve it with a join, and have seen joined records in the Records Browser such as `paymentoperation`, I have not been successful getting this field.